# Is there an easy way to identify your home system?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I quickly found a base and claimed it on the first planet after restarting my play through. It's pretty easy to locate when I'm flitting between planets in my home system, but I need to jump to another system to find some spadonium.

I've already done the one jump to get the antimatter blueprint, but had a bit of trouble picking out my "home" system. Luckily, I had renamed the system, so after a bit of trial and error, I located where I wanted to return to.

Is there an easier way to identify or a way to mark your home system in the galaxy map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the 1.3 Atlas Rising update, your home world is now marked in the Discoveries menu.

You can set a waypoint on the system and filter for custom waypoints in the galaxy map, if you want to plot a warp jump course home.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't appear to be an any markings denoting your home star system.

I think a good solution to the problem you had would be to use the teleporters that are now inside of each space station in every star system.  These teleporters can be found on the right side of the space station (after landing and your ship rotates).  When you teleport, you will be spawned inside of your base and your ship will be somewhere outside of your base.  This makes getting back to your base and ultimately the star system its in pretty fast.

Comment: I've tried to use the teleporters but apparently I need to warp a few more times to unlock them.

Comment: I didn't have that issue.  Have you just started the game?

Comment: As per my question: "after restarting my play through"

Comment: Ah sorry. I read that when I answered, but not again and forgot.  Well, keep warping until it works I suppose.  I can't find an answer about how many times you must warp before teleporters work.  It's kind of odd that there is even a requirement...

Comment: I guess they're expecting people to follow the Atlas path before settling on a base - or not expecting people to restart with a new save...